# Quiero crear una función para lanzar una instancia en AWS, y quiero pasar por parámetro el ID de la misma, pero me sale error, ¿alguna idea?

Tags: python-3.7, aws

```
import boto3
import json

region = 'eu-west-1'
#instances = ['i-098ab94df4f2c93a7']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=event['id'])
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        #'body': json.dumps('started your instances: ' +
        #str(instances))
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que aparece? Además, dale formato a tu código con el botón que indica `{}`, y lee [ask].

Comment: Pues si no nos comentas qué error te da va a estar dificil saber qué ha pasado y cómo se puede solucionar, no crees?